# Adding a potentiometer to an LM4910 as a volume control

Tags: amplifier, audio

Can someone tell me  where I need to place a potentiometer to control the volume in this LM4910 amplifier circuit?

Does the shutdown pin need a pull up resistor  to enable the IC?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to make R3 and R4 adjustable with a potentiometer. The other way would be to put a potentiometer on the output of the amplifier.

Be sure to use a dual potentiometer so both channels change the same resistance value, otherwise the channels will have different volume outputs (with two different potentiometer ) .

Comment: Putting pots on the output is unlikely to be successful, this is made for driving a 32 Ohm headset.

Answer (score 0):

Read the datasheet for the [LM4910](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4910.pdf) as this will tell you everything you need to know about the chip.
This amplifier is not really designed to use a physical volume control other than that provided by the equipment it plugs into. I imagine you would need an A-law stereo potentiometer on the input such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JM3RSMB) if you are trying to make a very small physical implementation:

[image]